# Problems Deserializing Nested Dynamic Types with ProtoBuf-Net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am trying to deserialize an object that is wrapped in several layers of DynamicType = true, using ProtoBuf-Net r668.

Using an older version of ProtoBuf-Net (v1), it will deserialize without a problem. With the latest version, however, it fails with

> ProtoBuf.ProtoException : Internal error; a key mismatch occurred

```
    [ProtoContract]
    private class A
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
        public object Body { get; set; }
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    private class B
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
        public object Body { get; set; }
    }
    [ProtoContract]
    private class C
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Try_Serialize_Nested_DynamicTypes()
    {
        var obj = new A() {Body = new B() {Body = new C() {Name = "Brian"}}};
        var serializer = new ProtoBufSerializer();
        var results = serializer.Serialize(obj);
        var g = serializer.Deserialize<A>(results);
    }
```

Comment: You just solved my problem! I was expecting that the "AsReference" switch was the problem (and already debugging protobuf-net source). But no - it is the DynmicType!

Comment: @marcgravell - I'm suffering the same issue. Any chance this got resolved or will be any time soon? Other suggestions to manage complex/dynamic contracts?

Comment: This still happens, how can we "turn around" this issue?

Comment: Echoing João, I've also just hit this issue and despite the flurry of new releases recently, it appears to have not been addressed. I guess I'll add an issue to Github, see if that gets any attention?